# Android map Api V2 blank mapview

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I have used this code for finding current position

googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();



    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));

    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Iam here!"));
```

I got crashe. Please help me

Comment: Post your xml and Android Manifest file....

Comment: blank means.my location button and zoom in and zoom out buttons are visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

try this worked for me

```
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        Location location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER); 
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 20000, 0, Context here); // requesting


        currentLocationLatLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude,
                currentLongitude);
        Marker location_present = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(currentLocationLatLng)
                .title("you are here")
                .snippet("")

                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_)));// adding
                                                            // marker
                                                            // on
                                                            // map
```

and override these

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // getting
    // updated
    // latlong
    // values on
    // changing
    // of user's
    // location
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();

    currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    lat.add(currentLatitude);
    lang.add(currentLongitude);
    latlang.add(currentLocationLatLng);
    Log.e("" + lat.toString() + "fsdf" + lang.toString(),
            "" + latlang.toString());

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```